# where are app scripts stored on Google Drive?

Tags: scripting, google-drive-api, directory, drive

I found a useful script long ago and installed it.  Now I want to delete it so it's no longer running, but I have no idea where it is stored so I can delete it. And I don't know it's exact filename to search for it.  How do I find the script??  it watches a shared folder on Google Drive and emails me when the contents of the folder are changed.

I need to find this script and delete it....   suggestions????

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? It uses Mime types to find the scripts.

```
function findGoogleScripts() {
    var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("GoogleScriptsOnMyDrive");
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ssNew);
    var sheet = ssNew.getSheets()[0];
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
    sheet.appendRow(["File Name", "Mime Type"]);

    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var mType, theFile;
        var tempArray = [];
        theFile = files.next();
        mType = theFile.getMimeType();
        if (mType.equals("application/vnd.google-apps.script")) {
            tempArray.push(theFile.getName());
            tempArray.push(mType);
            sheet.appendRow(tempArray);
        }
    }
}
```